# Tool to list down resultset from SQL Server for bulk data

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have many records with me for which I need to query the database. How can I write a query that can list down all the resultset at once using my large set of data?

The database that I used in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

do you want to get several selects on the same result set?
if yes, you can do

```
select column1, column2, column3 from table1
UNION ALL
select column1, column2, column3 from table2
```

you can union as many times you need, but of course you'll need to match the columns on both selects. If you use just UNION it will remove duplicate rows.